# jquery + php and mysql text boxes HELP?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, loops, textbox

I am trying to use a jquery to have text boxes and little pluses and minuses to add and delete them when required. It displays the data from MySQL but you can't delete them and you can only add them

Here is a link to a webpage i am using

http://adamlisik.co.uk/epq2/models/certificate.php?certid=250631166

I want to find a way that the text boxes that are displayed with the data from db can be deleted

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            // tworzymy zmienną i, wykorzystamy ją do identyfikowania wierszy
            // ustawiamy jej wartość 2, ponieważ jeden wiersz jest już w tabeli
            var i = 2;
            // tworzymy zmienną szablonWiersza i wczytujemy do niej szablon z textarea #szablon
            var szablonWiersza = jQuery.format($("#szablon").val());
            // tworzymy funkcję, która dodaje szablon do właściwej tabeli
            function dodajWiersz() {
                var ii = i++;
                // dodajemy wiersz do właściwej tabeli
                $(szablonWiersza(ii)).appendTo("#listaOsob tbody");
                // Nowy wiersz jest już widoczny.
                // Każdy element nowego wiersza posiada swoje id
                // tr na id: wiersz_2, ikona minus ma id: usunOsobe_2
                // Do nowo dodanej ikony - dodajmy zdarzenie.
                // W momencie kliknięcia minusa, wiersz zostanie usunięty.
                $("#usunOsobe_" + ii).click(function(){
                    $("#wiersz_" + ii).remove();
                });
            }
            // do przycisku #dodajOsobe dodajemy zdarzenie,
            // kliknięcie na przycisk plus wywoła fukcję dodajWiersz
            $("#dodajOsobe").click(dodajWiersz);
        });
    </script>


<h1>Sixth form baccaluraureate</h1>

<div id="content">

     <textarea id="szablon" style="display:none;" cols="1" rows="1">
        <tr id="wiersz_{0}">

            <td><input type="text" name="name[]" ></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="hours[]"></td>
            <td><input type="hidden" name="certificate_id[]"value="<?php echo $table2[0][2]; ?>">
            <td><img src="http://antczak.org/source/dynamic_forms/12.png" id="usunOsobe_{0}" alt="usun"></td>
        </tr>
    </textarea>

    <!-- Właściwa tabela -->

    <h4>activities form</h4>
    <form action="update_certificate.php" method="post">
    <!-- do not delete student is!!!! because we need it in confirm_cert.php-->
        <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="<?php echo $row[0] ?>" /> <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="student_id2" value="<?php echo $row[3] ?>" /> <br />

        <input type="hidden" name="certificate_number" value="<?php  echo $certificate_name; ?>" />
        <br/> 

        <table id="listaOsob">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Activity name</th>
                    <th>Hours</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
                <tr>
                <?php
                $a=0;
                while($a<sizeof($table2)){

                    echo "<tr><td><input type='text' name='name[]' value='".$table2[$a][0]."'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='text' name='hours[]' value='".$table2[$a][1]."'></td>";
                    echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='certificate_id[]' value='".$table2[$a][2]."'></td>";
                    #echo $a;
                    if ($a==0){
                    echo "<td><img src='../view/11.png' id='dodajOsobe' alt='dodaj'></td></tr>";
                    }else{
                    echo "<td><img src='../view/12.png' id='usunOsobe_{0}' alt='usun'></td></tr>";

                    }
                    $a++;
                    }
                ?>  
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could use the jQuery .remove() function.
http://api.jquery.com/remove/

Comment: As you can see I am alredy using that function !         $("#wiersz_" + ii).remove();